# Were weapon sound fx for D&D cartoon created specifically for the series?

Tags: sound-effects, dungeons-and-dragons-tv

When I look at the the image below, I am able to "hear" the sounds of the weapons in my mind:

[image: http://www.billsienkiewiczart.com/]

<sup>Artwork Credited to [Bill Sienkiewicz](http://www.billsienkiewiczart.com/)</sup>

For me, the sound effects for the weapons made the cartoon much more enjoyable.

Were these effects the product of some person (or team) sitting in front their tools (whatever they may have been at the time) and conjuring the best sound?

Or, would they have cycled through existing sound effects created over the years?

Comment: I don't have an answer, just a starting point. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085011/fullcredits#cast There's a list of people on the Series Sound Dept. Your best bet would be to contact someone on that list. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Watched part of an episode. Pretty standard library effects. Sound Ideas, Hanna Barbera, even a little Star Trek. Maybe some additional custom sfx created on synth (it was the 80s).

I'm a sound editor/mixer and these are the basic building blocks of the trade.